# keytool cannot import certifiate - failed to establish chain from reply

Tags: ssl-certificate, keytool, digital-certificate

I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on the following issue. I have read the keytool documentation but could not find any hint regarding what could be the problem here.

I created a keystore

> keytool -genkey -alias privateKeyName -keyalg RSA -keystore privateKeyName.jks -validity 720 -keysize 1024

I created a certificate request

> keytool -certreq -alias privateKeyName -keystore privateKeyName.jks -file certReqFileName.csr

After the signing authority gave me the .cer file, I tried to import it with

> keytool –import -alias privateKeyName -file certReqFileName_t_f.cer -keystore privateKeyName.jks

Import fails with

> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Failed to establish chain from reply

I have been stuck on this for some time now so any help would be awesome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Take a look at the option *-trustcacerts*, if your CA is listed in the truststore. Additionally you may have to add the CA's intermediate certificates to your keystore, first.

Comment: It took some time to accept this answer but it was really the intermediate certificates.

Comment: @Andy how exactly does one add the intermediate certificates?

Comment: @NikolaKolev the same way as other certificates. Take a look at the option `keytool -importcert`.